# Dproj files. What is the purpose of ImageDebugInfo?

Tags: delphi

our dproj files have this line in them:

```
<ImageDebugInfo>true</ImageDebugInfo>
```

I find no description of what this is. I did a google search and found other .dproj files that have this set on.

Anyone knows what this is for?

Thanks!

Comment: What Delphi version? And where in the .dproj file?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Linking probably Place debug information in separate TDS file. Easy to work out. Fiddle with the options until you see which one affects that setting. Or remove it from the dproj file and see how that affects dcc32 command line args.

Comment: @KenWhite It is a Delphi XE-2 Project. That tag is a sibling to DCC_DebugInfoInExe

Comment: Then I'd suspect it has to do with embedding TD32 debugging info in the executable (on the Linker tab in Project Options).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I created a new project in XE-10 Seattle. The 'ImageDebugInfo' is nowhere to be found. I then went ahead and set all values that were false to true using the IDE-> Options (for the project). Still tag does not show up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan did the same in XE-2 and the tag is nowhere to be found.
But if you do a google search on the internet for filetype:dproj it does show up. So it must have some meaning...

Comment: I found this comment next to that _ImageDebugInfo_ option in _Borland.Build.Task.Shared.dll_: "What is this for anyway?"

Comment: @Uwe that is fantastic!

Comment: @UweRaabe add it as an answer :-)